# MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Feed -- it returned 2

Tags: django, testing

I'm writing some simple test for a `django-model` and I'm just using `assertEqual` and `assertNotEqual` for it.
Now I'm not fully grasping how to test `BooleanField` in this case. I have a `model` field like this:

`duplicate = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

and I'm writing this test for it, just to check if it is equal:

```
def test_feed_duplicate_create(self):
    stefan_feed_duplicate = Feed.objects.get(duplicate='False')
    milan_feed_duplicate = Feed.objects.get(duplicate='False')
    self.assertEqual(
        stefan_feed_duplicate.duplicate, 'False'
    )
    self.assertEqual(
        milan_feed_duplicate.duplicate, 'False'
    )
```

But the error that I'm facing is:

```
(venv) vagrant@jessie:/var/www/vhosts/bspotted.net/app$ ./manage.py test --keepdb socialmedia
nosetests socialmedia --verbosity=1
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
............E....................
======================================================================
ERROR: test_feed_duplicate_create (app.socialmedia.tests.test_feed_model.CommentsTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/vhosts/bspotted.net/app/socialmedia/tests/test_feed_model.py", line 225, in test_feed_duplicate_create
    stefan_feed_duplicate = Feed.objects.get(duplicate='False')
  File "/var/www/vhosts/bspotted.net/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/vhosts/bspotted.net/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 338, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
socialmedia.models.feed.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Feed -- it returned 2!

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 33 tests in 0.159s
```

Can someone explain me what is the proper way of testing `BooleanField` in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis around the boolean and don't use `get`, `get` will throw an exception if multiple objects returned from the database. Use filter instead which will return the queryset objects `Feed.objects.filter(duplicate=False)` but if you want the object only then you can get the first object from the queryset results `Feed.objects.filter(duplicate=False).first()`

and then in your assert statement just user 
`self.assertFalse(stefan_feed_duplicate.duplicate)`

Comment: Ok, this is good, I've got it, now, thanks for explaining this to me

Comment: Do you have any fields in the mode that are unique, besides `id`? If yes, use them, if no use the `id`, to retrieve single object.

Comment: actually I have thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `get` method of `QuerySet` returns exactly 1 (one) entry. It will throw error if it can't retrieve an entry and it will throw an error if it retrieves more than one entry.

If you expect more than one entry, or eventually no entries at all, you should use the `filter` method, which returns itself a `QuerySet`.

In your particular case you can't just retrieve one entry based on the field `duplicate`. It is a `BooleanField` and there will be entries with value `True` and entries with value `False`.

You have to retrieve those particular entries for `stefan` and `milan` based on another field.

Answer (score 4):

This is usually the case, when multiple objects are selected by the selection that is specified in `get()`. In your case, multiple objects are fulfilling the criterion `duplicate == False`.

`get()` should only be used when you are sure that only one result is given back, e.g. by using the `id` as selector.

In your case you could use `filter()` instead of `get()` when you are expecting more than one result. However, `filter()` does not return an object but a `QuerySet`. You therefore have to adjust your asserts to compare the entries of the `QuerySet`.

Comment: Good answer, but the last sentence holds a pitfall. If he use `filter()` he'll get a `QuerySet`, which makes no sense in `self.assertEqual`.

Comment: Yes, it works for `filter` method, but it returns QuerySet. I want to filter further so I have to code `VizDataSerializer(list(queryset)[-1]).data['data']`

API: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet